# SQL: previous version from table example

Tags: sql, oracle10g, greatest-n-per-group

I need some help.
There is a table with full of data.
formtype, item_code, verion

So I have to select the actual formtype and item_code. (the biggest version of the actual version). I tried with max and greatest, but it didn't work. All version were selected.  But I dont know why.

For example:

the select was:

```
select formtype, item_code, max(version) 
from table_name;
```

the result:

[image: query result]

I tried greatest, but It worked the same.
So I need only the last version - actual version (9).
The table contains many thousand fromtype and item_code with different version.

And there is an other part of it.
If it gonna work, I need to select the previos version. (in the example means before the max of version).

I tried with subquery.

```
select b.formtype, b.item_code, max(b.version) from vps_form t,
(select formtype, item_code, version) b 
where t.formtype = b.formtype
and t.item_code = b.item_code
group by b.formtype, b.item_code, b.version;
```

So can sombody help what is the problem with it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were just missing the group by:

```
select formtype, 
       item_code, 
       max(version) 
from vps_form
group by formtype, item_code;
```

To get the latest and the previous version, this can be done using a window function:

```
select formtype, item_code, version
from (
  select formtype, 
         item_code, 
         version,
         row_number() over (partition by formtype, item_code order by version desc) as rn
  from vps_form 
) t
where rn <= 2
order by formtype, item_code, version;
```

Or if you need the latest and the previous versions as two columns in a single row:

```
select formtype, item_code, version, prev_version
from (
  select formtype, 
         item_code, 
         version,
         row_number() over (partition by formtype, item_code order by version desc) as rn, 
         lag(version) over (partition by formtype, item_code order by version desc) as prev_version
  from vps_form 
) t
where rn = 2
order by formtype, item_code, version;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2bd0f/2

Answer (score 0):

For the details of the records with max version, you can try the following query:

```
select formtype, item_code from tablename where version= (select MAX(version) from tablename);
```

For the details of the records with the second max version, you can use the following query:

```
select formtype, item_code from tablename where version=(select MAX(version) from tablename where version<(select MAX(version) from tablename));
```

Comment: This is not going to work correctly as you are retrieving the **overall** max. version, not the one specific for the combination of formtype and item_code.